# remove unnecessary words from string

Tags: php

I want to remove some words from string to make my image alt tag more relevant.

The problem is, if I have some phase like this:

```
barack obama at a restaurant in venice
```

I want the exit to be:

```
barack obama restaurant venice
```

but what I had is:

```
barack obamaa restaurantvenice
```

Code:-

```
$a = array( ' at ', ' in ', ' arriving ', ' a ', ' leaving ', ' walks ', ' walking ', ' her ' );
$str = 'barack obama at a restaurant in venice';
echo str_replace($a,"",$str);
```

if I use words without space in the array the result is much horrible:

```
brck obm resturnt venice
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `echo str_replace($a," ",$str); add one space inside `""``

Comment: You understand alt text is commonly used by screen readers for visually impaired people? Why would you want to remove words from it?

Comment: isn't it better for image SEO? @iainn

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add one space inside `""`like below:-

```
echo str_replace($a," ",$str);
```

Check here:-

```
<?php

$a = array( ' at ', ' in ', ' arriving ', ' a ', ' leaving ', ' walks ', ' walking ', ' her ' );
$str = 'barack obama at a restaurant in venice';
echo str_replace($a," ",$str);
```

Output:-https://eval.in/636890